# Android debug config error

Tags: android, отладка

В чем собственно проблема?

```
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.4.0'
compile 'com.android.support:design:23.4.0'

compile ('com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.1.0') {

    exclude module: 'okhttp'
}
compile 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.4.1'
compile 'com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-intercepto' +
        'r:3.4.0'
compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.1.0'
compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:23.+'
compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.+'
compile 'com.tonicartos:superslim:0.4.+'
compile 'net.danlew:android.joda:2.9.4.1'
compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.7.0'
compile 'com.wdullaer:materialdatetimepicker:2.5.0'
compile 'com.afollestad.material-dialogs:core:0.9.0.2'

compile 'net.opacapp:multiline-collapsingtoolbar:1.2.2'
compile 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:2.1.0'
compile 'com.turingtechnologies.materialscrollbar:lib:10.1.2'


compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-appindexing:8.1.0'
compile 'me.zhanghai.android.materialprogressbar:library:1.1.7'
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: а решение, которое предлагает AS пробовали?

Comment: Обычно подобное пишется, когда версия библиотеки `AppCompat` `24.2.1` не существует.

Comment: @NikotinN все пробовал

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Установите Android Support Repository и он Вам предложит решение.

Comment: Странно... раньше пытался сделать таким способом, не получилась. Щас сделал, все получилось. Очень странно! Ну все равно спасибо)